# Remove text "Joomla! 3.3.6" from admin panel

Tags: joomla, version, admin, panel, footer

Can someone give advice how to remove **Joomla! 3.3.6** from admin panel? I have found all the rest after "-" including copyright and website title but no luck with text **Joomla! 3.3.6**. Any ideas where to search?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Please ask your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove it go to this folder:administrator/templates/isis/html/mod_version/default.php.
And change this code by removing the "!" character in the "if" condition

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>
<?php if (!empty($version)) : ?>
<?php echo $version; ?>
<?php echo "&nbsp;&mdash;&nbsp;"; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove the text "Joomla! 3.3.6" from the admin panel you have to edit the following file:

`administrator/templates/isis/html/mod_version/default.php`

What you have to do in there it's remove all the code in there.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple solution without doing any code hacks:

1. Go to "Extensions" then "Module Manager"
2. In the left column, under "Filter" change "Site" to "Administrator" so that you are working with the Administrator modules and not the site modules.
3. Unpublish the module called "Joomla Version"
4. -- Or -- You can leave it published and tweak the available settings within.

Enjoy!